# interactive parsing 2 lines with awk or other utility maybe?

Tags: awk

I have program running in background and when it's received certain message, 
it will give output 2 lines like this:

```
09/09 15:28:29 Tx PL HouseUnit: A2
09/09 15:28:29 Tx PL House: A Func: Off
```

Now I want to parse word A2 and Off to publish mqtt message by issuing command:

```
mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t X10/"A2" -m "Off"
```

I'm thinking to parse with awk but my problem is awk only parse 1 line interactively.
Anybody has smart suggestion to resolve this issue?

```
awk '{if($3 == "Tx" && $4 == "PL" && $5 == "HouseUnit:") print $6; if($3 == "Tx" && $4 == "PL" && $5 == "House:" && $7 == "Func:") print $8} {system("mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t X10/127.0.0.1/switch/"$6 -m "$8) }'
```

code above only parse last line which execute

```
mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t X10/"A" -m "Off"
```

Comment: `I'm thinking to parse with awk` - put `getline()` between ifs. or just use a temp variable `if (second_line) { .... parse first line ... second_line=1; } else  { ... pase second line... system("run the command"); second_line=0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk '
    ($3 == "Tx") && ($4 == "PL") {
        if ($5 == "HouseUnit:") {
            foo = $6
        }
        else if ( ($5 == "House:") && ($7 == "Func:") ) {
            system("echo mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t X10/127.0.0.1/switch/\"" foo "\" -m \"" $8 "\"")
        }
    }
' file
mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t X10/127.0.0.1/switch/"A2" -m "Off"
```

(remove the echo after testing) but idk if calling that program from system() really makes sense vs just outputting the values from awk and calling it from a pipe to xargs or similar. Rename the variable `foo` to be something representative of whatever it actually means.